# Compare Hash Password Using HASHBYTES in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, hash

I have simple question:

```
print HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'az09123')
```

give me:

```
0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3enter
```

I put it in navchar field called OwnerEn

then I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers WHERE OwnerEn =  HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'az09123');
```

No results, it's empty

but this give me result:

```
SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers WHERE OwnerEn = '0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3';
```

What is the issue in first sql statement?

Comment: Maybe because function HASHBYTES returns varbinary, but your column type is varchar? Your are comparing different data types

Comment: It should be noted that if, as the title suggests, this is specifically for passwords, there are mistakes here compared to *good* password hashing - specifically the lack of salt and the choice of hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it works.

```
DECLARE @AspNetUsers TABLE (OwnerEn VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @AspNetUsers VALUES ('0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3')


SELECT *
FROM   @AspNetUsers
WHERE  OwnerEn  = master.dbo.Fn_varbintohexstr(HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'az09123'))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As Oscar mentioned in his comment, you are seeing no results because the `nvarchar` value `0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3` is different to the binary value `0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3`.

Ideally, you would be storing your hash values in an appropriate `binary` or `varbinary` data typed column, but if you absolutely cannot change that in your database, you need to `convert` your `nvarchar` value to `binary` or `varbinary`  (or vice versa) in order to actually compare the two values:

*Note the `1` at the end of the `convert`, to specify that you want to include the `0x` at the beginning*

`nvarchar` to `varbinary`:

```
convert(varbinary(max),'0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3',1)
```

`varbinary` to `nvarchar`:

```
convert(nvarchar(100),hashbytes('SHA1', 'az09123'),1)
```

This is demonstrated in the following script:

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', 'az09123') as BinaryHash
      ,convert(varbinary(max),'0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3',1) as NvarcharHash
      ,case when hashbytes('SHA1', 'az09123') = '0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3'
            then 'Match'
            else 'No Match'
            end as UnconvertedMatchTest
      ,case when hashbytes('SHA1', 'az09123') = convert(varbinary(max),'0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3',1)
            then 'Match'
            else 'No Match'
            end as ConvertedMatchTest
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|                 BinaryHash                 |                NvarcharHash                | UnconvertedMatchTest | ConvertedMatchTest |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| 0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3 | 0xA00592FC3E531C5F7608110F73E8AE4B4F2EA4C3 | No Match             | Match              |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive explanation

Comment: @PeterSmith and thank you for taking the time to show your appreciation 